# Mongo DB service getting stopped intermittently

Tags: mongodb

We have installed Mongo DB (v4.4.8) on our Windows Server 2016.

But the Mongo DB service stops very frequently, then we have to start the service again, which will run for few mins (varies from less than a minute to 10 mins), then will stop again. Sometimes the service will stop immediately.

We are able to access the DB and create collection when it is running.

I can see a folder that does not exist in our server in the Mongo DB logs.

*{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-14T16:55:22.194+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6F29F14EC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"**C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include/thread**","line":44,"s":"std::thread::_Invokestd::tuple<<lambda_726633d7e71a0bdccc2c30a401264d8c >,0>","s+":"2C"}}}*

The account with which we run the Mongo DB service is added as an Administrator on the server.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: That log line is part of a stacktrace.  Earlier in the log file there should be a message with a severity of "s":"E" or "s":"F" that indicates the error or failure.

Comment: Hi @Joe,
Below are the lines with error.

{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-19T04:04:37.008+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-19T04:04:37.009+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileRenameFailed: Access is denied\nActual exception type: class mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<37,class mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}

Comment: And there is the error: `FileRenameFailed: Access is denied`

Comment: @joe  Yes, but we already reviewed the permissions. We also tried running the service with a service account that is added as an admin on the machine and also as a network service account.

Comment: It is possible that error occurred while attempting to process another error, so look for an earlier one as well.  The file permission error might have been while attempting to write a core file.

Comment: @Joe I can deduce only two warning from the logs before the actual Failure msg appear i.e "message":"terminate() called.
1) "s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
2) "s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}

Answer (score 0):

Security tools were blocking Mongo DB files, due to which the service was keep on stopping intermittently because the files were not accessible for the Mongo DB service. Finally we had to exclude the Mongo DB folders from the security scanning to make it work temporarily.